# SQL Query Help! Using Selecting multiple

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query data that will allow me to use the SELECT statement to bring in multiple fields. Below is my code: (Which works for one specific field - [PDN005_Err]. How can I stretch that from looking only at 005 to PDN005 - PDN122, without having to hard code them into there?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT *
FROM OpenQuery(INSQL,
'
SELECT [DateTime], [PDN005_Err], [PDN005_Loc]
FROM Runtime.dbo.WideHistory
WHERE [DateTime] >= ''2014-03-01''
AND [DateTime] <= ''2014-04-01''
AND [PDN005_Err] = 1
ORDER BY [DateTime]
'
)
```

I am trying to query data that will allow me to use the SELECT statement to bring in multiple fields. Below is my code: (Which works for one specific field - [PDN005_Err]. How can I stretch that from looking only at 005 to PDN005 - PDN122, without having to hard code them into there?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

So as an UPDATE this is what I tried..

```
SELECT *
FROM OpenQuery(INSQL,
    '
SELECT [DateTime], [AGC005_ErrCond], [AGC003_ErrCond], [AGC005_Loc], [AGC003_Loc]
FROM Runtime.dbo.WideHistory
WHERE [DateTime] >= ''2014-03-01''
AND [DateTime] <= ''2014-04-01''
AND ([AGC005_ErrCond] = 1
OR [AGC003_ErrCond] = 1)
ORDER BY [DateTime]
    '
)
```

However, When I receive the data.. the value I'm looking for is 1.. however.. the data will keep repeating itself until one of the PDN Err = 1. Here's the attached picture so you can see.

Comment: you can autogenerate that query part in your code.

Comment: What's so bad about hard-coding them?

Comment: I tried hard coding them and the query didn't work, it would return a blank page. I have been reading up on SQL Queries and from I read they said it's not efficient to hard code values in there (takes a longer time to generate the data).

This code returns the blank page

    SELECT *
    FROM OpenQuery(INSQL,
    '
    SELECT [DateTime], [PDN005_Err], [PDN005_Loc], [PDN112_Err], [PDN112_Loc]
    FROM Runtime.dbo.WideHistory
    WHERE [DateTime] >= ''2014-03-01''
    AND [DateTime] <= ''2014-04-01''
    AND [PDN005_Err] = 1
    AND [PDN112_Err] = 1
    ORDER BY [DateTime]
    '
    )

Comment: was any of the answers helpful ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @data varchar(max)

;WITH x as
(
  SELECT number FROM master..spt_values WHERE number between 1 and 122 and type = 'P'
)
SELECT @data = 'SELECT [DateTime]'+ ( 
        SELECT ',[PDN'+right(cast(number+1000 as char(4)), 3) + '_Err]'
        FROM x
        for xml path(''), type 
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)') + ',[PDN005_Loc]
FROM Runtime.dbo.WideHistory
WHERE [DateTime] >= ''''2014-03-01''''
AND [DateTime] <= ''''2014-04-01''''
AND [PDN005_Err] = 1
ORDER BY [DateTime]'

exec( 'SELECT *
FROM OpenQuery([INSQL],'''+@data + ''')')
```

Note I would agree with the comment from @ThorstenKettner that hardcoding the columns would be better.

You should be aware that the maximum length of the query varchar in OpenQuery is 8 KB.

Answer (score 0):

Use information_schema.colums view to generate the column list

```
select column_name+',' from information_schema.colums
where table_name='WideHistory'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following approach.  First declare a variable to hold the column list.

```
declare @ColumnList as varchar(max)
```

Then use a loop to populate it.

Then add it to another variable.

```
@EntireQuery = 'select * from openquery(
INDSQL, ''select etc ' + @ColumnList + 
' from etc '')'
```

Then run your query:

```
exec sp_executesql @EntireQuery
```

Take note that with this approach you will need more single quotes than you have now.